# How to send mail from both Gmail and Ymail from an application using javamail api in android

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I am trying to make an application using java mail api. I want to send mail from both yahoo and gmail account. The code I use can send email from both yahoo and gmail account. But the problem is.... When the program is first run, if I send a mail from gmail account, then even if I enter a yahoo account in the 2nd time, the mail is sent from gmail account..!!! I don't understand what to do. please help...

MainActivity.java

```
.......
.......
if(sender.contains("gmail")){                   

                try {                       
                    GmailSender ss = new GmailSender(sender, password,1);                        
                    ss.sendGMail(sub,msg,sender,str);   
                } catch (Exception e) {   
                    //Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
                }
                }
                else if(sender.contains("yahoo")){

                    try {                       
                        GmailSender ss = new GmailSender(sender, password,2);                        
                        ss.sendGMail(sub,msg,sender,str);   
                    } catch (Exception e) {   
                        //Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
                    }

                }
```

GmailSender.java

```
public class GmailSender extends Authenticator {   
String mailhost;// = "smtp.gmail.com";   
private String user;   
private String password;   
Session sessionG;  

static {   
    Security.addProvider(new com.receme.sentmailbackground.JSSEProvider());   
}  

public GmailSender(String user, String password,int flag) {   
    this.user = user;   
    this.password = password;  


    if(flag==1)
        mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    else if(flag==2)
        mailhost = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
    Properties props = new Properties();   
    props.clear();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

    sessionG = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
}   

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
}   

**This part is edited**

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients, String attachment) throws Exception {   
        try{

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(sessionG);   
        //DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setSubject(subject);   
        //message.setDataHandler(handler)
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   


        BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart1.setText(body);

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);

        //for attaching file from sdcard

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
        String filename = attachment;

        if(!(filename.equalsIgnoreCase("no file is attached"))){

        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(filename,"/");
        String tempString = null;
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            tempString = st.nextToken();
        }
        System.out.println(tempString);


        //filename = tempString;

        messageBodyPart2.setFileName(tempString);        
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

        }

        //6) set the multiplart object to the message object
        message.setContent(multipart);

        //7) send message
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("success");

        }catch(Exception e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Attached File is not found");
            //Make a notification
        }
    }
```

//***************************//

```
public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
    private byte[] data;   
    private String type;   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
    }   

    public void setType(String type) {   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public String getContentType() {   
        if (type == null)   
            return "application/octet-stream";   
        else  
            return type;   
    }   

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
    }   

    public String getName() {   
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
    }   

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
    }   
}}
```

JSSEProvider.java

```
public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

public JSSEProvider() {
    super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
        public Void run() {
            put("SSLContext.TLS",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
            put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
            put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
            put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
            return null;
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: What change you did in this ...

Comment: Hello, I made some change in the sendMail class. I have edited it in the post. This work is quite old, So may there may be some mistake in variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made several of the [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: thank you for your answer. It is working now for yahoo and gmail both.

Comment: Can you edit the properties  which is working for yahoo @Receme